# Constrain 2 Views using visual format language

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, uikit

I got two views and i want that view1 has a top, bottom, trailing and leading space of zero to view2. How can i realize that using the visual format language ?
I know that i have to create a dictionary that assigns a string to a view and then i am able to define but thats it. It would be nice to get a hint on how to do this.

```
// Creating my dictionary
NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(childController.view,self.containerView);

// How to define the relation i described above ?
NSArray constraints = [NSLayoutconstrain constraintWithVisualFormat:...] 

// How to add the constraints to the actual view ?
```

Comment: The "hint" would be to read the docs which explain the visual format language to you: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html And the docs on UIView and NSLayoutConstraint also tell you how to all the constraints when you have formed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two `UIView`s named view1 and view2 -

```
[view1 addSubview:view2];

NSDictionary *views = @{@"view2" : view2};
NSArray *horzConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view2]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views];

NSArray *vertConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view2]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views];

[view1 addConstraints:horzConstraints];
[view1 addConstraints:vertConstraints];

view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```